# Какие отобрать признаки при классификации

Tags: машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Использую для классификации библиотеку scikit-learn, в частности случайный лес и градиентный бустинг. По причине, что качество и скорость классификации приемлемое.
Пробовал "опорные вектора", но слишком долго они просчитываются, но вопрос не в этом.

У меня есть несколько десятков признаков, большинство из них не улучшают модель. Сначала, я выбрал пару признаков, которые явно обладают какой-то предсказательной силой. Далее пробую добавлять один признак к той основной паре и перебираю лучшие гиперпараметры вложенными циклами. Если есть улучшения, то делаю пометку. Вообщем это довольно утомительно и долго.

Есть ли способ проверки признака за одну итерацию, не перебирая каждый раз снова гиперпараметры? Или быть может можно их оптом все сразу проверить.
     Да, встречал методы, тех же деревьев, чтобы отобрать признаки по степени важности или снижение размерности. Но, как-то они меня в свое время не впечатлили.
И еще те признаки, что я помечаю в целом совсем немного улучшают модель.
Когда допустим к старым двум я добавляю два дополнительно отобранных признака, то модель чаще работает хуже, то есть данные зашумляются что-ли?

Вообще в теории, если взять и использовать абсолютно все признаки, что есть, но при этом ограничить глубину деревьев, то модель по идее должна сама найти лучшие, а очередь до тех, что бесполезны просто не дойдет, так как есть ограничение в глубине деревьев(будет так работать)?

Comment: Интересно, удалось автору куда-то продвинуться? :)  Тема сложная, интересная. Там всё не просто :)

Comment: А что есть идеи для обмена?

Comment: Да ну идей то полно есть всяких, интересно, что у вас получилось. Одно время в моде было permutation importance считать. Есть вариант с отбором фич библиотекой boruta, её сначала не было для питона, а потом вроде перенесли. Есть разные методы отбора фич в  библиотеках для auto-ml всяких. Не говоря уже о старых методах типа RFECV из sklearn.

Comment: Ничего лучше прямого перебора не обнаружил. Вот так тупо и нудно. Радном форест точно не лучшая идея отбирать признаки. Тут еще один вопрос возникает, какие настройки использовать для модели, что отбирает признаки. Результаты плывут если использовать те или другие настройки для модели.

Comment: То-то и оно, что для разных моделей (и даже для одинаковых моделей, но с разными настройками) лучшие признаки могут быть разные. Поэтому когда стэкают модели, бывает, делают отбор признаков частью пайплайна для каждой из стэкаемых моделей отдельно. В общем, дело творческое. Я смотрел видео по результатам соревнований, у победителей часто очень развесистый пайплайн получался - очень много моделей, в разные модели разные признаки заходили и т.д. Жуть.

Comment: Искусство. Ага еще хорошо погоняют, на тестах, что потом на реале ни одного предсказания не происходит или мало)

Comment: Если реальные данные сильно отличаются от тренировочных данных, либо если с подготовкой данных где-то накосячили, то запросто ))  Но если нет таких крайностей, то кросс-валидация и усреднение по разным моделям должны помогать.

Comment: Ну это понятно, что в учебниках. Просто сложилось мнение, что если "слегка" переобучить модель, то результат будет лучше. Может не прав, пока думаю так.

Comment: Тут еще вот такие мысли: делим на 10 частей проверяем всякими там стратификациями и прочим. Но, если в данных мало информации, есть вероятность потерять закономерности чрезмерными проверками. Вообщем проверять нужно, как всегда. В одном одно сработает, в другом другое.

Comment: У меня, когда время и силы есть узучать, изучаю. А пока у меня у соседей сверху опять "припадки" начались бухают и орут. Сплю по три-четыре часа. Тут уже точно не до исследований) Здоровье как бы, что осталось сохранить, физическое и душевное.

Comment: Ну вот поэтому на кагглах и стекают и блендят сразу тучи моделей - чтобы как-то усреднить разброс разных моделей, глядишь, одни модели одно лучше нащупают, другие другое. Универсальных методов нет. И к жизни это всё не очень имеет отношение, в реальной жизни важнее простые модели, которые быстро считаются и легко интерпретируются, а не этот каггловский чёрный ящик, который даёт на 0.000001% лучше скор и жрёт ресурсы как паровоз.